# No way to get rsnapshot/rsync backup dot dir and file names

Tags: rsync, rsnapshot

I'm trying rsnapshot to get incremental rsync of my remote server (AlmaLinux 9) to my local desktop (Ubuntu 20.04) performed locally.
I found that a 8GB source directory was only 4GB at the target dir.

Executing rsnapshot the second time, the output of the rsync command shows is:
`/usr/bin/rsync -azv --delete --inplace --delete-excluded --relative --exclude=awstats --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh -p xxxx --link-dest=/path-to-target/alpha.1/. root@remote-host:/path-to-source/ /path-to-target/alpha.0/.`

I found that all `.dir` were not downloaded.
path-to-source/Maildir has some extra folders like .F1 .F2 .F3 .F4 ... .F10

The output of that rsnapshot/rsync was short this time:

```
receiving incremental file list     
path-to-source/Maildir/
path-to-source/Maildir/dovecot.index.cache
path-to-source/Maildir/dovecot.index.log
path-to-source/Maildir/.F3/
path-to-source/Maildir/.F2/
path-to-source/Maildir/.F5/  



sent 9,030 bytes  received 3,074,181 bytes  212,635.24 bytes/sec total size is 13,113,853,857  speedup is 4,253.31
```

A third execution of that command had a similar rsync output but

```
...     
path-to-source/Maildir/.F1/      
path-to-source/Maildir/.F4/       
path-to-source/Maildir/.F3/       
...
```

So, rsync starts receiving an incremental file list but it stops after a few `.dir` and outputs a report.

None of those `.Fx` files were downloaded neither any other `.file` nor `.dir`.

Almost all similar issues I've read mention the problem of using `*`.  I never used it, it is not necessary.
The option `-a` implies dot-dirs are included.

Other posts suggest changing MTU (!!) or pre execute `shopt -s dotglob`
None worked for me.
I'm, stuck here how to get rsync backup all dot-file and dot-dir.

Update 1:
Another try: at `rsync_long_args` rsnapshot config line I added `--include=".*"` (my first `*`!)
Strangely rsnapshot rsync command preview does not show the included option but the others.
It does seem to make the work, lots of files inside .F1 are being downloaded. I also have read that `--include=".*"` will exclude others,
but from [linux.die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

> --include=PATTERN       don't exclude files matching PATTERN

Update 2:
Letting cron do its job during the night I got a full backup.

Answer (score 0):

To get a full [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) backup including dot files and dot dirs I used `-a` and `--include=".*"` options of the command. Double quotes. Single quotes didn't work.
[from man rsync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVzJY.png)
Include pattern = DON'T EXCLUDE matching pattern